# How to remove admin notices from all pages except main Woocommerce page?

Tags: woocommerce, admin

I understand the need to notify admins about changes, hints, security issues etc.
But I don't want to be noticed on every single page in admin.

How can I remove ALL notices from admin pages except the main Woocommerce page?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current admin area screen with `get_current_screen()` and then remove notices based on viewed screen.

I think the main WP dashboard is the best place to display notices though, not the main WooCommerce admin page (not all notices are being displayed there natively). Anyway, you can use any admin dashboard ID as you wish:

```
add_action( 'in_admin_header', function () {

    $current_screen = get_current_screen();

    if( $current_screen->id != 'dashboard' ) {
        remove_all_actions( 'admin_notices' );
        remove_all_actions( 'all_admin_notices' );
    }
}, 20 );
```

Some examples of sreen IDs are:

- `dashboard` - main WordPress dashboard page
- `woocommerce_page_wc-admin` - main WooCommerce admin page
- `edit-shop_order` - WooCommerce orders table page

**However**, generally this is probably not a good idea, because *some* notices are meant to only show up on *some* screens and by limiting the notices to *some* screens only, you might never see some important warnings or errors.

Comment: Thank you, where do I put this? It has no effect in functions.php ...

Comment: @DønerM. Yes, `functions.php` is the right place. I just tested it on multiple sites and it works as expected. However keep in mind that **some** plugins don't use native WP notices and instead they use their own - this code will not get rid of those custom notices, you might need to use some additionals hooks for that.